# Formatting a java.util.Date through xsl built-in funciotn "format-dateTime" displays language

Tags: date, xslt, formatting

I'm using an xslt transformation to format a Java object to pdf through Apache FOP libraries.
In particular I want to format a field of my object, a java.util.Date into DD/MM/YYYY format. To be able to format using built-in function "format-dateTime" I set xslt version to 2.0 and switched the transformation processor to saxon-8.7 because xalan did not support version 2.0, then I added in the xslt the date formatting instruction as follows:

```
    Value date: <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(valueDate, '[D01]/[M01]/[Y0001]') " />
```

before starting the transformation, I printed the Date field to stdout to be sure it was valued correctly in the input object:

```
valueDate: Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 CET 1970
```

And that's what I expected.

But in the output text, after the xsl transformation, appears an undesired "language" information that precedes the (correctly formatted) date.

```
[Language: en]01/01/1970
```

Someone knows why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why did you choose Saxon 8.7? It's a very old release, it actually predates the XSLT 2.0 recommendation of January 2007. The current release is 9.5.

I think you will find this goes away if you use a more recent release. However, it could still happen if your Java configuration has a default Locale which is a language that Saxon does not support. (The message indicates that Saxon has chosen to output the date in English despite this not being the language you requested, which is implicitly your default language).

If moving to a more recent release fails to solve the problem, try setting the language argument of format-date to the string "en".

Comment: Yes, it was the language fallback that made the indesired string appear. Setting the language argument of format-dateTime to the string "en" worked. I can't switch to saxon 9.5 for reasons concerning project dependencies. 
Thank you very much.